# error_check raise ConnectionError

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I have a python code that uses the ebaysdk library, when i run the code and enter a keyword to search i get this error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ebay.py", line 9, in
>   
>       response = api.execute('findItemByKeywords', '53039031')   File
>
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebaysdk-2.1.5-py2.7.egg/ebaysdk/connection.py",
>   line 127, in execute
>       self.error_check()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebaysdk-2.1.5-py2.7.egg/ebaysdk/connection.py",
>
> line 223, in error_check
>       raise ConnectionError(estr, self.response) ebaysdk.exception.ConnectionError: u'findItemByKeywords: Internal
>
> Server Error, Domain: CoreRuntime, Severity: Error, errorId: 2000,
>   Service operation findItemByKeywords is unknown'

I am running it on python2 on ubuntu 17.10 and here is my code sample.

```
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection as finding
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

keywords = raw_input('enter your keyword(s) (eg: Television): \n')
api = finding(appid='JamesCan-HiMilesp-PRD-c246ab013-815fa751', config_file = None)
api_request = {'keywords':keywords, 'outputSelector': 'SellerInfo'}

response = api.execute('findItemByKeywords', api_request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

totalentries = int(soup.find('totalentries').text)
items = soup.find_all('item')
```

Please how can i fix this error?
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I replaced

```
response = api.execute('findItemByKeywords', api_request)
```

with

```
response = api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', api_request)
```

and it solved the problem.